# How to vertically scale Vert.x without Verticals?

Tags: java, vert.x, event-loop, vertx-verticle

According the the Vert.x docs - deploying using Verticles is [optional](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles). If this is the case - how can I deploy say an HTTP server onto multiple event loops? Here's what I tried - also read the [api docs](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html) and couldn't find anything:

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setEventLoopPoolSize(10));

HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions().setLogActivity(true);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  vertx.createHttpServer(options).requestHandler(request -> {
    request.response().end("Hello world");
  }).listen(8081);
}
```

This appears to create 10 HTTP servers on the first event loop but I'm hoping for 1 server per event loop.

Here's what I see in my logs - all eventloop-thread-0:

> 08:42:46.667 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG
> io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler - [id: 0x0c651def,
> L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8081 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50978] READ: 78B
>
> 08:42:46.805 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG
> io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler - [id: 0xe050d078,
> L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8081 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51000] READ: 78B
>
> 08:42:47.400 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG
> io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler - [id: 0x22b626b8,
> L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8081 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51002] READ: 78B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Optional" doesn't mean "you can, getting the same benefits". "Optional" simply means "you can".

Vert.x has the notion of thread affinity. HTTP Server created from the same thread will always be assigned to the same event loop. Otherwise you'll get nasty thread-safety problems.

You can compare the example code from above with the following code:

```java
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions().setLogActivity(true);

        // Spawn multiple threads, so EventLoops won't be bound to main
        ExecutorService tp = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(10);
        CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tp.execute(() -> {
                vertx.createHttpServer(options).requestHandler(request -> {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    // Slow the response somewhat
                    vertx.setTimer(1000, (h) -> {
                        request.response().end("Hello world");
                    });
                }).listen(8081);
            });
        }
        // Just wait here
        l.await();
```

Output is something like:

```
vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
vert.x-eventloop-thread-2
vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
```

That's because each event loop thread now is bound to a separate executing thread.

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible to write Vertx code that is multi-threaded without using Verticles? I'm also not clear what thread affinity has to do with this? I read this "Preparation methods such as createHttpServer or setTimer may be called from a non-Vert.x thread" here https://freecontent.manning.com/verticles-the-basic-processing-units-of-vert-x/.

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible. I said "you can". But, you won't get any benefits from that.

I updated my answer with some code examples.

Comment: That's helpful - I was trying to understand how verticals worked and this clarifies it. I would say there is a benefit for integrating Vertx with an existing executor based framework like Camel https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/vertx-websocket-component.html.